# No overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, methods, dataset, overloading, fill

I'm coding in Visual Studio 2013 using c#. I have a global string variable which is "order" as stated below code: Globals.order

```
private void frmPrint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cashierDatabaseDataSet.MALE_LINEUP' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.mALE_LINEUPTableAdapter.Fill(this.cashierDatabaseDataSet.MALE_LINEUP, Globals.order);
}
```

now, I want the `mALE_LINEUPTableAdapter` to be filled with the `cashierDatabaseDataSet` containing only the matched string value of `Globals.order` on `MALE_LINEUP table`.

I've found a similar condition at MSDN which instruct me code it like this:

```
customersTableAdapter.FillByCity(northwindDataSet.Customers, "Seattle");
```

but it gives me error:

> "No overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments"

please can someone help me!

Comment: Did You define Fill method with this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have skipped over the first part of the walkthrough that *created* a `FillByCity` method that takes two parameters.  The base `Load` method just takes one parameter - the table to load.

Follow the instructions in the walkthrough to create a similar `FillByOrder` method, and pass the parameter to that method.